# Задача "Класс Matrix"

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, инспекция-кода, матрицы

> Реализуйте класс Matrix. Он должен содержать:
>
> Конструктор от списка списков. Гарантируется, что списки состоят из
>   чисел, не пусты и все имеют одинаковый размер. Конструктор должен
>   копировать содержимое списка списков, т. е. при изменении списков, от
>   которых была сконструирована матрица, содержимое матрицы изменяться не
>   должно. Метод **str**, переводящий матрицу в строку. При этом элементы
>   внутри одной строки должны быть разделены знаками табуляции, а строки
>   — переносами строк. После каждой строки не должно быть символа
>   табуляции и в конце не должно быть переноса строки. Метод size без
>   аргументов, возвращающий кортеж вида (число строк, число столбцов).

Путем мученических мучений собрала "сборную солянку" из похожих кодов на форумах, получилось вот такое:

```
from sys import stdin
from copy import deepcopy


class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = deepcopy(matrix)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([''.join(['%d\t' % i for i in row]) for
                          row in self.matrix])

    @property
    def size(self):
        rows = len(self.matrix)
        cols = 0
        for row in self.matrix:
            if len(row) > cols:
                cols = len(row)

        return (rows, cols)


# exec(stdin.read())
m = Matrix([[1, 1, 1], [0, 100, 10]])
print(str(m) == '1\t1\t1\n0\t100\t10')
```

и вот данные, которые указаны в самом низу кода отрабатывают некорректно - нужно, чтобы выходило `True`, а выходит `False`. Что не учтено?

тесты проверяющей системы с результатами:

```
Тест 1
Входные данные:
# Task 1 check 1
m = Matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
print(m)
m = Matrix([[2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 10000]])
print(m)
m = Matrix([[-10, 20, 50, 2443], [-5235, 12, 4324, 4234]])
print(m)

Вывод программы:
1   0
0   1
2   0   0
0   1   10000
-10 20  50  2443
-5235   12  4324    4234



Тест 2
Входные данные:
# Task 1 check 2
m1 = Matrix([[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
m2 = Matrix([[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
print(str(m1) == str(m2))

Вывод программы:
True



Тест 3
Входные данные:
# Task 1 check 3
m = Matrix([[1, 1, 1], [0, 100, 10]])
print(str(m) == '1\t1\t1\n0\t100\t10')

Вывод программы:
True
```

[image: тест 1 на скрине почему-то выглядит иначе]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему у вас лишняя табуляция в конце каждой строки и функция возвращающая размерность работает с ошибками.

Попробуйте так:

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = deepcopy(matrix)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,row)) for row in self.matrix)

    def size(self):
        return (len(self.matrix), len(self.matrix[0]))
```

Comment: что-то теперь первые тесты не проходят именно из-за пробелов/табуляций...попробую на выходных поразбираться. В любом случае, большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-osnovy-programmirovaniya/programming/albda/klass

Comment: @Lazarevna, у этого курса нет бесплатного 7-дневного доступа, как у других курсов :(

Comment: .... странно ....я бесплатно прохожу

Comment: @Lazarevna, странно, вот, что они пишут: “This course doesn't have a 7-day full access free trial,“

Comment: а может такое быть, что я прохожу у Высшей школы экономики платный курс, и поэтому этот бонусом идет?

Comment: Возможно, точно не скажу...

Comment: я почему ссылку дала - я скопировала тесты и результаты, но то, как они выглядят здесь и там - это не одно и тоже ... попробую картинку добавить

Comment: добавила внизу скрин  теста 1

Comment: @Lazarevna, честно говоря, не вижу чем не доволен "coursera autograder"

Comment: так и я .... если сама не осилю до ума довести, напишу преподавателю. А то как теперь жить и мучиться, совершенно непонятно ))) Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Lazarevna, обычно у каждого курса на Курсере есть форум где как раз обсуждают почему "автогрейдер" не принимает ответы - мне такие форумы несколько раз здорово помогли...

Comment: там обсуждали, что вместо copy  нужно использовать deepcopy

Comment: @Lazarevna, мы с вами сфокусировались на методе `__str__()`, а проблемы, похоже, были с методом `size()` ... ;-)

Comment: Это невероятно !!!! ))) Вы их всех победили!!!!! ) СПА-СИ-БО!!! )

Comment: а что же все-таки до этого было не так?